# Good tools for diagnosing Smartphone problems

Tags: android, ios, mobile, diagnostics

So with the great proliferation of mobile OS's out there, troubleshooting problems on a single users phone is a really tricky issue these days. Does anyone know of any good diagnostic tools that will collect OS level, installed apps / version info and other configuration settings  and then can be copy, pasted and e-mailed back for further review and troubleshooting?

It looks like Apple has something like this that their Genius Bar staff uses but I wasn't really able to find anything definitive that didn't require an Apple Employee user id. Would appreciate any other tips/tools that have proven useful when developing and troubleshooting particularly thorny application problems on smartphones (particularly interested in iPhone and Android but anything generic would be useful as well).

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google ACRA.

There are others as well... but ACRA is totally free and GREAT!

Comment: So I found this link (http://stablex.blogspot.com/2012/08/android-crash-reports-libs-and-services.html) but ultimately am looking for a standalone app that a user can download and then send diagnostics to an e-mail address, etc.

Comment: acra is more of a your app crashing send diags thing, not proactively collect info and send.  Although with some effort you could marry the two and get what you want.  Since acra provides plenty of that info already.  Also the google dev console does provide some basic info (again about you apps and the devices they are installed on only.)

Answer (score 0):

For iPhone you have [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465).

Here is the description of it.

*iPhone Configuration Utility lets you easily create, maintain, encrypt, and install configuration profiles, track and install provisioning profiles and authorized applications, and capture device information including console logs.*

*Configuration profiles are XML files that contain device security policies, VPN configuration information, Wi-Fi settings, APN settings, Exchange account settings, mail settings, and certificates that permit iPhone and iPod touch to work with your enterprise systems.*

Here is a question on this in android forum [Android Configuration Utility & Remote Control.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30725). You can also check [this for android](http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/410210-how-configure-100s-androids-automatically.html) and [this](http://udm4.com/S/configuration_utility_android/).

Comment: The iPhone Configuration Utility requires Mac OSX. Looking for something that will run on the phone itself. I also looked at the Android posts but they all seemed related to installing and configuring the OS, not getting diagnostics on it.

Answer (score 0):

"MonkeyTalk is a simple-to-use tool with incredible power. Automate real, functional interactive tests for iOS, Android, Web/HTML5, Hybrid, and Flex apps - everything from simple `smoke tests` to sophisticated data-driven test suites."
http://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk

Comment: MonkeyTalk is an automation framework I believe, correct? I'm looking for something like ACRA that will pull version and diagnostic info. Does MonkeyTalk do that? I couldn't understand from the website whether it did or not.